# Which drive is better to keep a swap?

Tags: ssd, swap

I have a laptop with a processor core i5. 4 GB of RAM.

The laptop has a built-in hard disk SanDisk **SSD** U100 24GB [10.52.01] (**/dev/sda**). Read speed 270 MB / s, write speed of 78 MB / s.

In addition, I set another disc Corsair Force 3 **SSD** (5.02) (**/dev/sdb**). Read speed 217 MB / s, write speed of 216 MB / s.

Question: 
If the system is on disk **/dev/sdb5**. Which drive is better to keep a swap?

Comment: I do not think you are going to notice any difference in performance wither way. Sure you can benchmark it, sdb writes faster, sda reads faster, are you doing more writing or more reading to swap? how often? are you even using swap?

Answer (score 0):

Corsair Force 3 is better disk for memory swapping, although you won't notice the difference. You have 4 GB of ram, so I suggest to set swappness to lower value than the default 60.